# .htaccess 301 for new structure from /blog/name to /blog/article/name

Tags: url, htaccess, redirects, .htaccess, apache

The title really says it all. I am by no means an .htaccess wizard.

I rebuilt the site and have an old URL of:

```
http://domain.com/blog/whatever
```

I need all these to redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/blog/article/whatever
```

I have tried various things, but to keep the question/answer clean, I will leave them out since they didn't work.

Comment: This seems like a question for stackoverflow, it's not really about EE is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure / able to get .htaccess working, then maybe you would be better off installing the Detour Pro add-on for EE - which lets you do redirects like this via a CP module.  Works well and supports both EE2 and EE3.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I just did separate redirects in htaccess. Would still like to know how to write it to process all though. I really don't want to do this via addon and add any overhead to EE.   ;)